# c# MediaPlayer only plays file ONCE

Tags: c#, wpf

Greeting. I have a instance of a MediaPlayer and it works but I need it to play every time I click the button. I have it assigned to the tag of the button and I have the Open method that assigns the file I want already wired up. The first button click plays the file but *subsequent clicks do nothing*. Please advise.

```
        mp.Open(new Uri(myFile));


    public void playSou(object g, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = g as Button;
        MediaPlayer mp = (MediaPlayer)b.Tag;
        mp.Play();
    }
```

Comment: You need to set the position of the stream back to zero.  The mp contains a stream and when you finish playing the stream is at the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks, that's it
            MediaPlayer mp = (MediaPlayer)b.Tag;
            mp.Position = new TimeSpan(0);
            mp.Play();